# Get user with highest points

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, highest

I want to get the User with the highest points in SQL. I have this Table:

| userId | points |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |

Now, I want to get the userId where the points are highest? In this example it where user 3, but how I can do this automatically is SQL?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you please check the code below=>

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (userId int,points int);

INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(2,0);
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(3,4);
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(3,2);
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(2,5);
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(1,5);
```

**THIS ss for MYSQL 8.0**

```
   WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT USERID,
           points,
           RANK() OVER(ORDER BY points DESC) RNK
    FROM USERS 
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    WHERE RNK=1
```

**NOTE:** Check output in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mWZG26pnEbuzb5Yyd7qoe4/1).

Comment: Thanks for the Awnser! But is there a way to do this in Mariadb 10x too?